# Attempting to access View from blade template causes blank body in Laravel4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a project which is using laravel4 and its blade view engine. Occasionally I have had the need to call controller methods via a view file to output dynamic data; incidentally this time its a call to a method that generates javascript code for the page. Regardless of whether this is the best way to go about things is a moot point atm as I am simply upgrading from L3 to L4.

My View is similar to:

```
@extends('en/frontend/layouts/default')

{{-- Page title --}}
@section('title')
    Page Title
    @parent
@stop

{{-- Page content --}}
@section('pageContent')
    ...
@stop

{{-- Scripts --}}
@section('scripts')
    <?php echo CaseStudy::script(); ?>
@stop
```

I have set up CaseStudy to load via the laravel facades and the class at current is simply:

```
class CaseStudy
{

    public function display()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Returns the javascript needed to produce the case study
     * interactivity
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|void
     */
    public function script()
    {
        $language = \Config::get('app.locale');

        $scriptElementView = $language . '.frontend.elements.casestudy_script';

        if ( ! \View::exists($scriptElementView))
        {
            $scriptElementView = "Training::" . $scriptElementView;
        }

        return \View::make($scriptElementView, array());
    }
}
```

It would appear that echoing the response of CaseStudy::script is what is causing the blank body; however with no further error message I do not know what is going on. I assume that this is because my static CaseStudy's instance of View is conflicting with the instance being used by the blade engine. How would I go about having CaseStudy::script() returning a string form of the rendered view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view

```
{{-- Scripts --}}
@section('scripts')
    {{ CaseStudy::script() }}
@stop
```

In your library

```
class CaseStudy
{
    public function script()
    {
         $string = "your script here";
         return $string;
    }
}
```

Note - CaseStudy should really be a "library" or "helper" or something. Not a controller - that does not really conform to MVC approach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes this code is within a helper class which is part of a package. I found that the bug was nothing to do with View and more to do with the laravel3 method `URL::to_route()` having crept into my laravel4 view code. Once I fixed that it all ran fine - its just a shame that blade breaks debugging or I would have caught this sooner.